# How to generate a report file using facebook Jest

Tags: node.js, bamboo, jestjs, grunt-jest, gulp-jest

Im using [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/) to run unit tests on my application.

Is there a way I can get it to generate any sort of report file? I would like to integrate the report with [Bamboo](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo).

Comment: Generally, you'd need something that will output in xUnit.xml format for this — [this sample project on Github](https://github.com/palcu/jest-example) does exactly that, but can't get it working for the latest version of Jest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

install this

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-junit

add this on your jest.config.file

```
"reporters": [
        "default",
        ["jest-junit", { outputName: "junitreport.xml" }]
    ]
```

on bamboo use the junit parser, configure it to find file in this way

**/junitreport.xml